# How to do a prefix search for guid that is analyzed by the standard analyzer?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I have the below model and my prefix query doesn't return results. How can I get it to work with Guids? It works for other data types.

```
public class Customer 
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}

//Query
query.Prefix(p => p.Name, "a") //Works
     .Prefix(p => p.Id, "a") //Doesn't work
```

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your Customer index?

Comment: @Val It's using the standard analyzer so it's mapped as a text field.

Comment: Can you share the mappings and settings please `GET customer`?